# Putting jQuery Autocomplete in External .js File

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm wanting to create a somewhat generic jQuery Autocomplete function that I can use in multiple pages in my asp.net web application.  I have the code working when all the jQuery is in the same aspx page as the textbox that is tied to the autocomplete.  I want to put the autocomplete function in a separate .js file that I can then call from multiple aspx pages.  I've tried implementing this and it's not working.  What is happening is that when I open (show) the div that contains the asp textbox (used for the autocomplete), the page just hangs with my "loading please wait..." message. The main changes I made when moving to the separate .js file was adding parameters so that I can pass in the textbox ID as well as WebMethod name and file. I've looked at many examples on Stackoverflow as well as other sites to try to figure out what I am doing wrong, but haven't been able to identify the issue.  Below is a copy of the function I created in the .js file as well as the script block I have at the bottom of my aspx page.

Here is the contents of my .js file:

```js
function InitAutoComplete(textBox, methodFile, methodName, hiddenFieldForSelectedValue)
{
    $(textBox).autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request, response)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: methodFile + "/" + methodName,
                data: "{ 'searchString': '" + request.term + "', 'limit': '10' }",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item)
                    {
                        /*return {value: item}*/
                        return
                        {
                            value: item.ID,
                            label: item.Program
                        };
                    }))
                },
                error: function (result)
                {
                    alert("No matches found!");
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui)
        {
            if (ui.item)
            {
                //GetCustomerDetails(ui.item.value);
                document.getElementById(hiddenFieldForSelectedValue).value = ui.item.value;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        },
        focus: function (event, ui)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
}
```

Here is the script block on my aspx page:

```js
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null)
{
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e)
    {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null)
        {
            InitAutoComplete("#<%=ProgramNameSearchTbx.ClientID %>", "LessonsLearned.aspx", "GetMatchingProgramNames", "<%=SearchRecordNumberHF.ClientID%>"); 
        }
    });
};

$(function () {
    InitAutoComplete("#<%=ProgramNameSearchTbx.ClientID %>", "LessonsLearned.aspx", "GetMatchingProgramNames", "<%=SearchRecordNumberHF.ClientID%>"); 
});
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code but if you moved `InitAutoComplete` function to a separate js file, make sure that the function is declared before it's being used in your aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where the issue was, but I deleted the function from the .js file and recopied it in from the working aspx file, made the changes so I could pass in the parameters and now it is working.  This replacement code below also contains the original "$(function ()" wrapper inside the function definition.  I know that missing element was not the cause of the original issue, but I did want to point that out.

Here's the working function located in my .js file:

```
    function InitAutoComplete(textBox, methodFile, methodName, hiddenFieldForSelectedValue) {
    $(function () {
        $(textBox).autocomplete(
            {
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: methodFile + "/" + methodName,
                        data: "{ 'searchString': '" + request.term + "', 'limit': '10' }",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                /*return {value: item}*/
                                return {
                                    value: item.ID,
                                    label: item.Program
                                };
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("No matches found!");
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        //GetCustomerDetails(ui.item.value);
                        document.getElementById("<%=SearchRecordNumberHF.ClientID%>").value = ui.item.value;
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
    });
}
```